# Have Python (2.7) replace %d with nothing

Tags: python, nonetype

I have something like

```
for cnt in range(1,33):
    someFunction(%d)
```

I built some syntax upon this idea and then discovered that `%d` should be replaced by (nothing) instead of 1 within the function during the first call (when `cnt == 1`). So I tried this

```
for cnt in [None] + range(2,33):
    someFunction(%d)
```

But that doesn't work. I need to pass some integer into the functions as an argument to prevent an error.

Of course I could change the function definitions (and use an empty string) but that would be quite a bit of work.

Is there an elegant workaround for this?

**UPDATE 0**

There's actually a whole bunch of functions where I wrote `someFunction`. They're all built on the assumption they'll get a single integer argument. I'd have to go through all of them in order to pass an empty string into them.

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks all for your comments. I guess the only option is to modify the functions themselves so they'll accept a string argument which'll be empty for `cnt == 1`.

Comment: What is `%d` supposed to do, anyway? That's not valid Python syntax.

Comment: What should the input be for `someFunction`, exactly?

Comment: If you pass nothing, what will happen to `someFunction`?

Comment: What is replacing the argument with nothing supposed to mean? Skip that call? Or do you really want to do some string operation, and do you want to provide an empty string? Or are you still figuring out exactly what you want the code to do?

Comment: I've something like `table%d` in the function. When looping, that returns `table1`, `table2` and so on. However, `table1` is called `table` (which I didn't expect).

Comment: Can you update the question with some actual valid Python code? %d really means nothing in particular

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm on Python 2.7. %d is a placeholder for an integer.

Comment: Can you change the function to use `%s`? Then you _can_ just pass the empty string

Comment: Pity. The original interpretation of the question was more interesing

Comment: @gnibbler Yeah. The q was unclear.

Comment: @gnibbler: I could use `%s` with an empty string but some basic calculations may occur in the different functions so that'll require quite some work...

Comment: ...and you've learnt to refactor that common code out earlier next time. :)

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood you correct ... if, this should do the trick:

```
for cnt in range(1,33):
    if cnt == 1:
       someFunction()
    else:
       someFunction(cnt)
```

(untested)

Comment: No, the function should run for `cnt == 1` too but in this case `%d` should stay empty. (It should render "table" for "table%d"%cnt.)

Comment: The question makes it look like `%d` is some sort of placeholder. Your comment makes it look like the parameter is used with a format string?

Comment: your previous answer is equivalent to current, but deserviving credit instead of current. not your fault question is too ambigous (btw, that -1 is not mine)

Comment: @frlan: someFunction() throws an error ("...takes 1 argument...")

Comment: You can set a default value for the function ... something like `def someFunction(counter = None)` should work

Comment: @frlan: sure but calling `someFunction()` then renders `TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for cnt in range(1,33):
    someFunction(*[] if cnt == 1 else [cnt])
```

If you want to be (more?) cryptic

```
for cnt in range(1,33):
    someFunction(*[cnt][:cnt!=1])
```

Comment: Wouldn't the first one passes `[2]` to the function?

Comment: @alKid, no it passes `*[2]` etc.

Comment: `someFunction(*[])` returns TypeError: someFunction() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: @RubenGeert, yes  your questioni was quite unclear. _ALL_ the answers you got chose the same wrong interpretation, so it can't be our fault

Answer (score 1):

What you want is something like

```
'table{:d}'.format(cnt) if cnt > 1 else 'table'
```

inside your function

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'd call this "elegant," but:

```
for cnt in [""] + map(str, range(2,33)):
    someFunction(cnt)
```

Comment: I thought about that but someFunction needs an integer argument in order to function.

Comment: @RubenGeert: Then you should think about redesigning `someFunction`. Maybe have `someFunction` itself handle not printing the `1`?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a job for decorators:

```
def func_selector(func):
    def wrapper(*argv, **kwargs):
        if len(argv) ==0 or argv[0] == 1:
            return func()
        else:
            return func(argv[0])
    return wrapper

@func_selector
def someFunction():
    pass  # Function declaration here.
```